# How to further approach array comparison and creating new csv file with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, csv

(me === rooky in Javascript)

i'm using csv.js https://github.com/knrz/CSV.js to process csv files into an array.

```html
<script src="csv.js"></script>
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
  //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
  var f = evt.target.files[0];
  if (f) {
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = function(e) {
  var contents = e.target.result;
  var csv = new CSV(contents).parse();
  console.dir(csv);
  }
  r.readAsText(f);
  } else {
  alert("Failed to load file");
  }
  }
  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
  </script>
```

While that is working fine it's raising some questions...

1. When using the constructor

   ```
   var csv = new CSV(contents, {header: true}).parse();
   ```

it results in name/value pairs sorted in alphabetical order. Is there any way to keep the original order?

```
Ablesedatum:"16.11.2016"

Fakturierungszyklus:"..something.."

Kontonummer:200000000

Location:20000197777

Name:"Customername"

Produktbeschreibung:"productname"

Quelle:"CUSTOMER"

Seriennummer:3333333333

Status:"Billed"

Transaktionsart:"read usage"

Vertrag:3400000000

Vertragsart:"PagePack"

Zählerbeschreibung:"Total Prints"

Zählernummer:"ZBWT"

Zählerstand-Wert:92366
```

2. When using the constructor

   ```
   var csv = new CSV(contents).parse();
   ```

it results in just Arrays keeping the order of the .csv but of course no name/value pairs and all formatted as string. So it goes from 0 to 16.

3. What i want to do after the .csv file is parsed is the following:

compare the arrays for "Seriennummer" and "Zählernummer" and "Ablesedatum".
Ablesedatum is just the date of reading.

Then i want to grab the one with the most recent date and write that into a new var.

Comparison should be configurable, while i'm not sure about the conditions for comparison

After i am done i should contain a a bunch of arrays cleaned of all the unneeded Arrays.

Now i have to grab parts of the content of multiple lines "filtered" by "Seriennummmer" and "Zählernummer" and now the oldest Date and write all the informations i need into a single line.
Then i will write it back to a .csv again :-)   (seems to be supported by the api)

Hope i've been specific enough. (sorry i'm not a native speaker)

P.S.
Would be interesting to do this with more than one file at the same time ...

Comment: no, there are different usecases. this is just the example for my question about comparison

Comment: well. obv. this questions was too big ....